# Custom UITableCell IBOutlets are "broken" (objects become nil) on runtime, for the UITableCells used for display in the Search Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My main view controller (an UITableViewController), will have a search bar, that when tapped will bring up a search controller (also UITableViewController) that will draw cells identical to the main one. My tableview.cellfor method was getting confused with dequeing my custom cell (even though the identifiers have been set correctly and the interface builder objects have the correct class) so I have used the tableview.register method to register my cells (even though the cells are practically identical to the ones in the main view controller, I made them a different class and reformed them in the interface builder). I am now getting the bug that the IBOutlets that I made in my swift files for the search controller table view cells are broken, and my cell elements are set to nil, any help with that?
Here is the UITableViewCell code for the search cells

```
class SearchBeerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
@IBOutlet weak var beerNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var beerDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var selectBeerButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func selectBeerButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed")
}

func update (with beer: Beer) {
    self.beerNameLabel.text = beer.name
    self.beerNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.beerDescriptionLabel.text = beer.toString()
}
}
```

and here is the search controller method cell for row at

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Am ajuns pana aici")
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchBeerCell", for: indexPath) as? SearchBeerTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("Could not dequeue cell!")
    }
    cell.update(with: beers[indexPath.row])
    cell.selectBeerButton.tag = indexPath.item

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

The line for registering the cell was this

self.tableView.register(SearchBeerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "searchBeerCell")

Comment: You cannot *reuse* prototype cells designed in one table view in another table view. If you want to use a custom cell in different table views create a XIB

Comment: I recreated the prototype cell in my other tableview, it's all independent of the original prototype. Can that still cause some issues?

Comment: If you use prototype cells you **must not** register the cells in code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am still learning and haven't used XIB files before, only the Main.storyboard. I will look into using the XIB. Should I create the table view in it, or just the content view?

Comment: Only the content view (the cell).

Comment: I've made a XIB file for the content view of my prototype cells for the search table view, and a correspondent class (BeerView). I've changed the content view class to my new BeerView class, the content view from the main storyboard, and I've connected that view to the search table cell class through an IBOutlet. But I am still getting the 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier searchBeerCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' error message, or if I register the prototype cell it breaks the connections. What could fix this?